# deinit called but the uint testing not finished

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctestcase, coordinator-pattern

I'm trying to test my coordinator flow but the child coordinator `deinit` called before the unit test case finished

My coordinator class

```
public final class AppCoordinator: Coordinator {

        public var childCoordinators: [Coordinator] = []

        public var navigationController: UINavigationController
        var window: UIWindow?

        public init(window: UIWindow?) {
            self.window = window
            let secController =  SecController()
            self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secController)
            secController.delegate = self

        }
        public func start() {
            window?.rootViewController = navigationController
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }

    extension AppCoordinator: SecControllerDelegate, SignInControllerDelegate {
        public func removeSingIn() {

            self.childCoordinators.removeFirst()
        }

        public func showSignIn() {
            let signInCoordinator = SignInCoordinator(navigationController: self.navigationController)
            signInCoordinator.delegate = self
            self.childCoordinators.append(signInCoordinator)
            signInCoordinator.start()

        }

}
```

Unit test class

```
class AppCoordinatorTests: XCTestCase {
    var coordinator: AppCoordinator!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        coordinator = AppCoordinator(window: UIWindow())
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        coordinator = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testStartMethod() {
        coordinator.start()
        XCTAssertNotNil(coordinator.window?.rootViewController)
    }

    func testShowSignIn() {
        coordinator.showSignIn()
        XCTAssertFalse(coordinator.childCoordinators.isEmpty)
        XCTAssertTrue(coordinator.navigationController.visibleViewController is SignInController)
        }
}
```

when try to test `testShowSignIn` always failed because of the `deinit` call `removeSingIn` function

```
public class SignInController: UIViewController {

    public weak var delegate: SignInControllerDelegate?

    public init() {

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        self.delegate?.removeSingIn()
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you instantiate `SignInController`?

Comment: in SignInCoordinator

Answer (score 0):

Let's review the steps:

- `testShowSignIn` calls `coordinator.showSignIn()`, where `coordinator` is an `AppCoordinator`.
- `showSignIn()` instantiates a `SignInCoordinator`, and sets its delegate to the `AppCoordinator` instance.

Now we reach the important part:

- We reach the end of `showSignIn()`. The `SignInCoordinator` goes out of scope, so Swift destroys it.

Nothing maintains a reference to the `SignInCoordinator`. But you want to test the interaction between the `AppCoordinator` and the `SignInCoordinator`. The code is fighting you, because `AppCoordinator` decides to create and destroy the `SignInCoordinator` on its own.

You can test it by changing the design. You have a couple of options.

**Option 1:** Change `AppCoordinator` to have a lazy computed property that returns the `SignInCoordinator`. This can work if you're okay with that design. Then the `SignInCoordinator` will continue to live, so that the test can query it. This improves the testability of `AppCoordinator` by exposing the `SignInCoordinator`.

**Option 2:** Have the test create a `SignInCoordinator` and *pass it in* as an argument to `showSignIn()`. Then the `SignInCoordinator` lifecycle will be managed completely outside of `AppCoordinator`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm trying to declare lazy property `lazy var signInCoordinator: SignInCoordinator = {
  
  return SignInCoordinator(navigationController: self.navigationController)
 }()` and use it in `showSignIn` but the same issue

Comment: Try adding a deinit to SignInCoordinator that prints something. Then run the one test. What does the test log show?